# PassKit error message: Invalid data error reading pass pass.com.*****

Tags: wallet, passkit

I'm using the [sample code from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/iOS/Wallet_Support_Materials/WalletCompanionFiles.zip) to try to create my first Wallet demo.

I'm following the [Wallet Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/YourFirst.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH2-SW1).

After changing the passTypeIdentifier and teamIdentifier information as below.

"passTypeIdentifier" : "pass.com.*****",
  "teamIdentifier" : "******",

I use signpass to generate the .pkpass file. It succeeds.

But then when I run the .pkpass file, I get this error from system log.

> Invalid data error reading pass
>   pass.com.******/nmyuxofgna. The passTypeIdentifier
>   or teamIdentifier provided may not match your certificate, or the
>   certificate trust chain could not be verified.
>
> ERROR: Error Domain=PKPassKitErrorDomain Code=1 "The pass cannot be
>   read because it isn’t valid." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The
>   pass cannot be read because it isn’t valid.,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x6000037e8090 {Error Domain=PKPassKitErrorDomain
>   Code=1 "The passTypeIdentifier or teamIdentifier provided may not
>   match your certificate, or the certificate trust chain could not be
>   verified." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The passTypeIdentifier or
>   teamIdentifier provided may not match your certificate, or the
>   certificate trust chain could not be verified.}}}

I'm pretty sure the certificate is correct, it is just generated from developer center.

Comment: having the same issue!, Also noticed that if I put a wrong identifier the signpass tool returns errors, so I would be expecting that when it doesn't return errors the .pkpass generated would be ok!

Also worth to mention that the pkpasses included in the walletCompanionFolder open correctly in MacOSX, while trying to edit one with the team identifier and pass identifier doesn't work.